# Changing csv export header from default database header

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, csv

This code is under my models folder. This is supposed to get details from the database and generate a csv report of it. How can I change the first row of the export? The first line goes aud_id, aud_datetime, etc which is the database name of the fields. How can I customize it?

```
public function get_by_hardware($har_barcode)
    {
        $this->db->join('hardware_asset', "hardware_asset.har_barcode = {$this->table}.aud_har");               
        $this->db->join('employee', "employee.emp_id = {$this->table}.aud_per", "left outer");
        $this->db->where('aud_har', $har_barcode);  
        //$this->db->where('aud_per', null);
        $this->db->order_by("aud_id","desc");
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table); // 
        return $query;

    }
```

All help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use `as` clause with select. which will replace the column names.

Comment: Your code shows how you get the data from the db. If you want to change the first row of the csv, I would do to it at the place where the csv is generated, just add the first row and then data data from the database. Maybe you can show us the code where the csv is generated?

Comment: @Mario A, yes that will work but what if sql will change? You have to change your headers again and again... better change one place than two.

Answer (score 0):

Alias => `as` is that you are looking for, if you write sql like that :

```
SELECT col1 as myNameForCol1, col2 as myNameForCol2 ... FROM ...
```

then u should get what u need. As i see you are using some kind of query builder so probably you have to do something like this:

```
$this->db->select(array('col1Name'=> 'aliasForCol1', ...));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Column Aliases directly in your select statement to format the output.

Example:

```
$this->db->select('column1 AS `Custom Column 1`, column2 AS `Custom Column 2`');
```

But, you'd have to specify all the columns you want to select in the statement.